# Searching for a certain sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

How do I search OEIS for a certain sequence? For example I want the number of ways $1, 2, 3,\ldots, n$ can be arranged so that the numbers in the even places are greater than their neighbours.

Comment: **What did you try?** For example, did you try computing the first few values of your sequence and putting that in...?

Comment: @Zev Chonoles Yes. For n=1,2 there are no solutions. For n= 3, there are 2 arrangements. For n=4, there are 8 arrangements. For n=5, there are  12 arrangements. So in the search box I  entered 0, 0, 2, 8, 12, but got no relevant results.The only sequence shown is   Number of nonempty subsets of {1,2,...,n} in which exactly 1/4 of the elements are <= (n+2)/3.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know whether the problem is with the description or with the counting, but your description doesn’t match the counts that you give. I’ll assume that the description is correct.

There is vacuously $1$ arrangement for $n=1$. (If in doubt about possible vacuous cases, typically for $n=0$ or $n=1$, omit them: as long as you enter a sequence of consecutive terms, a match will be recognized.) For $n=2$ there is also one arrangement, $12$. For $n=3$ there are, as you say, $2$. For $n=4$ there are $5$: $1324,2314,1423,2413$, and $3412$. For $n=5$ there are $16$: $13254,23154,14253$, $24153,14352,34152,24351,34251$, and their reversals. Feeding $1,1,2,5,16$ into OEIS produces $85$ returns, of which the first is the right one: this is [OEIS A000111](https://oeis.org/A000111), the sequence of [Euler zigzag or up/down numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_permutation).

Comment: I cannot comment so I am writing it as an answer. Thanks very much for your help. So what you are suggesting is that to find some sequence in OEIS, I have to calculate the sequence for small values, and then enter the consecutive values in the search box? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @qwertyuiop: You’re welcome. Yes, you need a string of consecutive values. It can start anywhere. I’m cautious about starting with $n=0$, because that case is sometimes treated a little oddly, so I might try both with and without what I think it should be. And of course the longer the string, the fewer possibilities you’ll get back. Finally, if I get no match on something that seems very likely to be in OEIS, I recalculate my values.